# I'd like to select all values from all databases

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle 12c with many databases that come and go.  I can run "select * from all_users" and get a list of all of my users databases.  Now I can specify which user's table I want to query, but I'd really like to query them all.  So something like "select * from all_users.client" to get all clients from all users.  I know that won't work, and frankly, there may be no way to do what I want here, but if there is please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is your friend.

Comment: I think you mean "from all **tables**", not databases

Comment: Point of order: your phrases "many databases that come and go" and "list of all of my users databases" sounds like you are conflating 'database' with 'user'.  Maybe you come from a MSSQL background, where the term 'database' means something completely different than in oracle.  In oracle, databases have users and users have tables. Users do not have databases, and databases do not tend to 'come and go'. Also in oracle, the term 'user' and 'schema' are almost synonymous, a 'schema' being the collection of objects owned by a specific user..

Comment: Are all the databases part of the same [container](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/multitenant-overview-container-database-cdb-12cr1)?

Answer (score 0):

I created a SQL script that you can run to export all the information from all the tables (that you have access to). Using SQLcl, you can `set sqlformat csv` so that any select that you run returns the columns comma delimited. You can also modify the select statement that is gathering the table names to limit the tables that you want to return.

Also note that I ran into some tables that had characters in the table name that are not valid for a file name. For example, I have some tables that have `$` in the table name, but that is not a valid character for a file name so if you run into that scenario you may want to add a correction for that.

```
set pagesize 0
set linesize 20000
set heading off
set feedback off

spool export_tables.sql

  SELECT 'spool ' || owner || '.' || table_name || '.csv' || chr(10)
      || 'select * from ' || owner || '.' || table_name || ';' || chr(10)
      || 'spool off'
    FROM all_tables
   WHERE owner NOT IN ('SYS',
                       'SYSTEM',
                       'OUTLN',
                       'DBSFWUSER',
                       'AUDSYS',
                       'DBSNMP',
                       'APPQOSSYS',
                       'XDB',
                       'WMSYS',
                       'OJVMSYS',
                       'CTXSYS')
ORDER BY owner, table_name;

spool off;

set sqlformat csv
set heading on

@export_tables.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get all the tables of the user:

```sql
select * from all_tables order by owner, table_name;
```

It returns the user-name and table names